# How to search google doc filetype from google?

Tags: google-docs, google-search

Is it possible to search for google docs documents/filetype from google search engine?

I know it's possible to search for `.doc` file types like so `trucks filetype:doc`

But is it possible to search for google doc filetype only?

Comment: Probably not. I don't know of a way to do that.